# Object doesn't support this property or method when setting a property that is a custom object

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two custom classes. One is the property of the other. I am trying to set the value of the property from outside the class, inside an Access form.

I'm at a loss here. I tried to remove the set keyword and the result was it executed the Let but said value was not defined. It also fails if I try to set it to Nothing. (I know dog isn't really a property of an animal, this is just for illustration.)

```
'Animal class
Private dog As Dog    
Public Property Get oDog() As Dog
    Set oDog = dog
End Property '<<<Error happens here.

Public Property Let oDog(myDog As Dog)
    Set dog = value
End Property

'If I don't do this, I get an object variable or with block variable not set error.
Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set dog = New Dog
End Sub

'Dog class
'Dog properties and methods here.

'Form
Private oAnimal As Animal

Set oAnimal = New Animal
Set oAnimal.oDog = New Dog '<<< that fails
```

My end goal here is to set an object property of a custom class to a new object, but from outside the class, from a form. The bottom line is, for some reason the getter is being called instead of the "letter" when I call Set. I know I'm doing something wrong, I just don't know what it is. I'm sure its obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Let you use "myDog" and then set dog to value try changing it to :

```
     Public Property Let oDog(Value As Dog)
         Set dog = Value
     End Property
```

Comment: This, along with not using the Set keyword, fixed my problem. It WAS obvious! Thank you for pointing out my error. I'm used to C# where value is a keyword.